# How to change the back ground color of winforms panel when it hosted in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I want host a winform Panel control in WPF by using WindowsFormsHost,after that,I found that I can't change the backcolor of hosted panel,or it's not working when you set BackColor="SomeColor".Any one has an idear?

```
    <WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="1">
          <WinForms:Panel x:Name="VideoPanel" BackColor="Black" Dock="Fill"/>
    </WindowsFormsHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution,set window AllowsTransparency="False"